# How can I create many windows programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

As the titles says, I wonder if it is possible to create a windows programatically. Basically I want to create spawn a window at a random location on the screen when the user press a button. The problem I have is that if i create a view in runtime, it will disappear immediately after its created.

So is there any way to create windows, and then add them to an array and keeping them allocated?

Comment: Please post the code what you have tried so far. Then we can help in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's disappearing as soon as you're creating it is because you *haven't* added them to a (preferably ***mutable***) array yet.  As soon as your function exits, the window gets deallocated and it goes away.

Create a "`@property`" or "ivar" for your mutable array (e.g. in your app delegate `*`) and as soon as you create your window, add the window object to that array and your window will likely not disappear.

note: `*` = app delegate is a terrible place to keep things, but for the purposes of getting you up to speed I'd recommend doing this to start with.